# Knockout JS get previous element in array

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I use Knockout JS to populate table rows with array "editAutoHoldDetails" (as given in the code sample). Instead of priceRangeLowEdit, I want to populate priceRangeHighEdit of previous element in the array.
For example, my JSON looks like below. In the second element of the array, I want to populate priceRangeLow (1000) with priceRangeHigh of previous element (2).

Please suggest a solution.

```
JSON:[{"baseLineErrorThresholdDown":100,"baseLineErrorThresholdUp":100,"prevTickErrorThresholdDown":50,"prevTickErrorThresholdUp":100,"priceRangeHigh":2,"priceRangeLow":0},
    {"baseLineErrorThresholdDown":0,"baseLineErrorThresholdUp":0,"prevTickErrorThresholdDown":0,"prevTickErrorThresholdUp":0,"priceRangeHigh":0,"priceRangeLow":1000}]

<tbody data-bind="foreach: editAutoHoldDetails" id="editAutoHoldDtlTblId">
 <tr>
    <td align="center" data-bind="text: priceRangeLowEdit"></td>
    <td align="center"> <input data-bind="value: priceRangeHighEdit"/></td>
    <td align="center"> <input data-bind="value: baseLineUpEdit"/></td>
    <td align="center"> <input data-bind="value: baseLineDownEdit"/></td>
    <td align="center"> <input data-bind="value: prevTickUpEdit"/></td>
    <td align="center"> <input data-bind="value: prevTickDownEdit"/></td>
</tr> 
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
<input data-bind="value: $parent()[($index()-1)].priceRangeHigh()"/>
```

We use `$parent` which in case of foreach binding return observable array and `$index` which returns the index of current element in loop.